# How to make inline-block contained by outer div?

Tags: html, css

**Here is the example:**
http://jsbin.com/ecuCAME/1/edit?html,css,output

**HTML:**

```
<div>
    <a href='#'>texttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttext</a>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
div {
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px dashed black;
}

div a {
  word-wrap: break-word;
  display:inline-block;
}
```

How to wrap anchor and preserve `display: inline-block` property in its style?

Comment: Do you want the anchor not to flow out of the div?

Answer (score 3):

Add `width: 100%` to `div a {}` CSS definition.

```
div a {
  word-wrap: break-word;
  display:inline-block;
  width: 100%;
}
```

[**Working demo**](http://jsbin.com/ecuCAME/5/)

Answer (score 2):

For the [`word-wrap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/word-wrap) property to work you have to specify the `width` property of the `anchor`.

[**jsBin Demo**](http://jsbin.com/ecuCAME/7/edit)

```
div a {
  word-wrap: break-word;
  display:inline-block;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is that what you mean? [live example](http://jsbin.com/ecuCAME/12/)

```
div {
    width: 200px;
    border: 1px dashed black;
    overflow: hidden;
}

div a {
    word-wrap: break-word;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly just edit your

```
width:200px;
```

to

```
width:100%;
```

but maybe I just don't understand the question

Answer (score 0):

this should work when u using it like [this](http://jsbin.com/ecuCAME/14):

```
div {
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px dashed black;
}

div a {
  width: 100%;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  display: inline-block;
}
```